# Align multiple Images (vertically aligned to the middle) with captions aligned along the baseline

Tags: html, image, css, flexbox

I've been trying to do this for a while now and can't come with a solution that works for me. Im getting images from a DB with different heights and i need to vertically align them to the middle with the captions horizontally align at the end of each image.

Please notice that all the images are cut in a different way i can't change that so it doesn't matter that they don't look aligned because of that.

Update: The figure captions (spans) might have different heights too.

[Here's a Pencode](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qqEQpg)

[Here's what i need to accomplish](https://postimg.org/image/p9mtd86a9/)

Will REALLY appreciate some help.

```
<section class="new-products container">
<div class="image-row">
        <!--PRODUCT BLOCK-->
          <div class="product-block col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <figure>
              <img src="https://s21.postimg.org/wr1wb9z0n/test2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Foto Producto">
              <figcaption>
                <span class="category">category</span>
                <span class="product-name">Product Name</span>
                <span span="" class="price">price 6€</span>
              </figcaption>
            </figure>  
          </div>  
        <!--PRODUCT BLOCK END-->
        <!--PRODUCT BLOCK-->
          <div class="product-block col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <figure>
              <img src="https://s21.postimg.org/z9nlbykqv/test1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Foto Producto">  
              <figcaption>
                <span class="category">category</span>
                <span class="product-name">Product Name</span>
                <span span="" class="price">price 6€</span>
              </figcaption>
            </figure>  
          </div>  
        <!--PRODUCT BLOCK END-->
        <!--PRODUCT BLOCK-->
          <div class="product-block col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <figure>
              <img src="https://s21.postimg.org/h84ge5qpz/test3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Foto Producto">  
              <figcaption>
                <span class="category">category</span>
                <span class="product-name">Product Name</span>
                <span span="" class="price">price 6€</span>
              </figcaption>
            </figure>  
          </div>  
        <!--PRODUCT BLOCK END-->
        </div>
```

```
.image-row {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-ms-flex-align: baseline;
-webkit-align-items: baseline;
align-items: baseline;
-webkit-box-align: baseline;
-moz-box-align: baseline;
}

.new-products {
    text-align: center;
}

.product-block .category, .product-block .category-special {
    font-size: .75em;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.product-block {
    margin: 0 0 2em;
}

.product-block span {
    display: block;
}

.product-block .category, .product-block .category-special {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: .063em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.product-block .category {
    color: #b10832;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did the following to your code:

1. Remove the `baseline` alignment for `image-row`
2. Make the `figure`s a column `flexbox` and apply these styles:

   ```
   .product-block figure {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     height: 100%;
   }
   .product-block figure img {
     border: 1px solid red;
     margin-top:auto;
   }
   .product-block figure figcaption {
     margin-top:auto;
   }
   ```

Have also added a border around the image for illustration. Let me know your feedback on this, thanks!

Demo below:

```css
.image-row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  /*
  -ms-flex-align: baseline;
  -webkit-align-items: baseline;
  align-items: baseline;
  -webkit-box-align: baseline;
  -moz-box-align: baseline;
  */
}
.new-products {
  text-align: center;
}
.product-block .category,
.product-block .category-special {
  font-size: .75em;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.product-block {
  margin: 0 0 2em;
}
.product-block span {
  display: block;
}
.product-block .category,
.product-block .category-special {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: .063em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.product-block .category {
  color: #b10832;
}
.product-block figure {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
.product-block figure img {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-top:auto;
}
.product-block figure figcaption {
  margin-top:auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<section class="new-products container">
  <div class="image-row">
    <!--PRODUCT BLOCK-->
    <div class="product-block col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://s21.postimg.org/wr1wb9z0n/test2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Foto Producto">
        <figcaption>
          <span class="category">category</span>
          <span class="product-name">Product Name</span>
          <span span="" class="price">price 6€</span>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <!--PRODUCT BLOCK END-->
    <!--PRODUCT BLOCK-->
    <div class="product-block col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://s21.postimg.org/z9nlbykqv/test1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Foto Producto">
        <figcaption>
          <span class="category">category</span>
          <span class="product-name">Product Name</span>
          <span span="" class="price">price 6€</span>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <!--PRODUCT BLOCK END-->
    <!--PRODUCT BLOCK-->
    <div class="product-block col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://s21.postimg.org/h84ge5qpz/test3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Foto Producto">
        <figcaption>
          <span class="category">category</span>
          <span class="product-name">Product Name</span>
          <span span="" class="price">price 6€</span>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <!--PRODUCT BLOCK END-->
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hey @kukkuz thanks a lot ! this worked like a charm for me and i will check your answer as the solution since its way cleaner and way more easy to make it responsive. Any comments on the crossbrowsing for this ? I mean i know the implications of using flexbox on this regard but any extra feedback ? Many thanks !

Comment: Just one thing @kukkuz if any of the spans grows (more height) then the whole figcaption wont be align with the one next to it.

Comment: @Lowtrux if the span are multi-line, then this solution may not work...

Comment: Yeah unfortunately the spans can be multiple line, any ideas ? thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Wrap each images inside a div ie,

```
<div class="image-holder">
<img src="https://s21.postimg.org/wr1wb9z0n/test2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Foto Producto">
</div>
```

and apply equal heights to these divs using match height js plugin (http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/). And then

```
.image-holder {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.image-holder img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.image-holder:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: -.25em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Praveen, your solution is not working for me tho, the image captions are aligned to the baseline but the pictures are still not vertically align in the middle (js plugin is working ok tho). Ive tried with and without the display flex on the container since you have not mentioned if thats still necessary but still not working.

Comment: .image-holder{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  height:700px;
}

.image-holder img{
  border:2px solid red;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  display:inline-block;
  width:auto;
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

.image-holder:before{
  content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: -.25em;
}

Comment: image-holder height is just for the demonstration purpose. If you are using match height plugin just remove it.

Comment: will your answer work if the caption spans are multiline ? Thanks !

Comment: Yes I think. Could you try that

Comment: The 100% height on the .image-holder:before is causing the image to totally overflow the .image-holder div. You can see whats going on here https://postimg.org/image/9hdbs3jzl/.